# pdfjs not opening links in separate window using LinkTarget.BLANK?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pdf.js

Can't get **PDFjs** to open links in a separate window, tried inserting

> PDFJS.externalLinkTarget = PDFJS.LinkTarget.BLANK;

```
/sites/all/libraries/pdf.js/build/pdf.js
```

but after having cleared the cache they still open in the same window.

even tried commenting out

```
PDFJS.openExternalLinksInNewWindow = (
  PDFJS.openExternalLinksInNewWindow === undefined ?
    false : PDFJS.openExternalLinksInNewWindow);
```

FYI: Using this in Opigno LMS where a Slide renders the PDF with pdfjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I **upgraded from pdf 7.x-1.9 to the current 7.x-1.x-dev version** with drush and cleared the cache it is working now, even when I reverted back the code so perhaps it's part of the new dev version :)